# WSUS installation user

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I am currently in the process of installing and configuring a WSUS server for my company's local network, I have one doubt though regarding the installation process.  I've not been able to find anywhere which user should be used for the installation of the WSUS services, what I mean by "which user" is pretty much if a Domain Administrator user should be used, a local Administrator user or should I create a specific WSUS domain user with specific rights for this installation?

I appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about the user account installing WSUS, and not the user account the WSUS service runs as.

I don't think there's a specific rule listed anywhere.  That said, WSUS doesn't require Domain Administrator privileges, or even a domain at all.  (We used to use it in a 5,000 PC workgroup environment by adding registry keys.)  Any of the accounts you mentioned would work, and you can use whichever account is convenient.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for your answer, that's exactly what I needed to know.